# Wireless and hardline network

Tags: networking, ping

The networks I set up use wireless AP's connected both with hardline and wireless backhaul across a satellite for internet. I use a combination of Vivato, Engenius 2610's and MicroTik RB433's with three DLink switches and two Catalyst 2960's. Everything comes directly into a Catalyst 2960 before it goes out to the router (MicroTik RB1000). There are also users that are hardlined directly to the router.

I can understand why at different times I may not be able to ping the remote back hauled radios, but why would I not be able to ping everything that is hardlined back to the main router on a consistent basis, that is what I don't understand. It is a 100Mb network so there should be plenty of BW.

Most of the radios ping continuously but there are some that won't ping certain times of the day, say in the evening, then the next morning they start coming back, even then the pattern isn't consistent. There are no more than about 150 users connected. I have tested the cables and they all pass. I am connected with my laptop to the main router.

I use FreePing so I can ping multiple devices at one time. Right now I have a Catalyst 2960 in the network I cannot ping but yet users/wireless traffic is going through it without any difficulties as the users are getting on the internet. My question is, why can I ping devices sometimes and other times I can't when they are hardwired in the system?

Comment: "They've cut the hardline, it's a trap. Get out!"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into weather-related issues, especially if these radios are outside.  Condensation can cause issues.